# How to access image from storage

Tags: laravel, storage

I have a file saved in storage/app/uploads and I would like get this this image saved and show with img src tag.

But I can't

I am trying:

```
public function getSlider(Request $request)
    {
        $slider = Slider::find( $request->input('id') );    
        $slider->imagem = storage_path('storage/app/uploads/'.$slider->imagem);

        return response()->json( $slider );
    }
```

And I am trying show with jquery and javascript

```
function getSliders() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('#token').val() }
        })
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('site.getSlider') }}",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            id: $('#id').val()
          }
        }).done( r  => {
             console.log('r',r)
             $('#description').val( r.description )
             setImage( r.image )
        })
    }
```

And setting Image

```
function setImage( image ){
    var newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.setAttribute('src', image);        
    newImage.width = 500;
    newImage.heigth = 200;
    document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
}
```

When I want access image from public/img I use

```
<img src="{{ URL('img/myImage.png') }}">
```

But I want to access from storage/app/uploads

[image: age]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This return the file route (no url) (if you see the log it says /var/www.... etc)

```
storage_path('storage/app/uploads/'.$slider->imagem);
```

You should use asset helper to create URL of image

```
asset( 'storage/app/uploads/'.$slider->imagem);
```

Before this you need to run this command to create symbolic link to storage folder from public folder.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: The url has been changed, but it doesn't find the file, yet!

Comment: Could you dump the URL? how it looks? did you run the artisan comand?

Comment: Yes, I run the command. The url now is  http://localhost:8000/storage/app/uploads/2018-12-26-manaus1.jpg

Comment: Please try to save the picture inside storage/app/public/uploads when you upload the picture. The storage link is pointing to storage/app/public.

Answer (score 1):

try save your images in public folder instead of storage
its simple you can access it by using public_path() function.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, run this command:

`php artisan storage:link`

Then in any view you can access your image with the help of **url** helper.

`url('storage/app/uploads');`